# Cannot install python cityhash

Tags: python-2.7

I have been trying to install city hash for a project using pip. I have also tried to create a fresh virtual environment. But it ends up throwing a lot of errors and aborts. I am using python 2.7 and Mac Os High Siera. Here is the list of errors.

> Command "/Users/sajidur/Desktop/venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/vl/g0c89v2d6qs_bgtczn62m45r0000gn/T/pip-install-RFumZd/cityhash/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/vl/g0c89v2d6qs_bgtczn62m45r0000gn/T/pip-record-CKcTkr/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/sajidur/Desktop/venv/include/site/python2.7/cityhash" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/vl/g0c89v2d6qs_bgtczn62m45r0000gn/T/pip-install-RFumZd/cityhash/
>       (venv) Sajidurs-MacBook-Pro:Desktop sajidur$